# Laravel, grabar form desde modal y uno segundo una vez que se cierra?

Tags: php, laravel, crud, id

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar en PHP y Laravel estoy desarrollando un CRUD para guardar dos FORM, uno directamente desde un modal, y el segundo una vez que el primero se guardara,  pero al ejecutar o darle al botón de guardar me marca lo siguiente:

El primer form del fondo aparece el "Registro" donde llega un conductor, en caso de que no este se hace un proceso para tomarle foto y agregar sus datos.

[image: Modal]

Y una vez capturado aparece este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Estuve investigando y varios sitios y sugieren poner un ID en el form.

Codigo de las inputs:

```xml
<!-- Drivername Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('driverName', 'Driver Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('driverName', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
    
<!-- Licence Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('licence', 'Licence:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('licence', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
    
<!-- Imagelicence Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('imageLicence', 'Licence Image:') !!}
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="custom-file">
            {!! Form::file('imageLicence', ['class' => 'custom-file-input']) !!}
            {!! Form::label('imageLicence', 'Choose file', ['class' => 'custom-file-label']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Codigo para guardar:

```xml
@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Create Driver</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="content px-3">
        @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
        <div class="card">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'drivers.store', 'files' => true]) !!}
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    @include('drivers.fields')
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                <a href="{{ route('drivers.index') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}    
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Otro detalle es que ambos FORM utilizan el siguiente código para guardarlo,

```
 {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
```

otra cosa que realice fue colocar un iframe para abrir dentro del modal la pagina para crear un nuevo conductor pero requiere de mas acomodos para ajustar la pagina. De antemano muchas gracias a quien me llegue a responder.

Comment: No entiendo en dónde está el problema desde el primer párrafo de tu explicación, si pudieras retroalimentar, ayudaría a poder darte alguna respuesta

Comment: Verifica la validación que tengas en la acción del controlador que recibe la url `'drivers.store'`.